How to Produce a Cross Patonce in LaTeX?
The following image of a Cross Patonce is taken from The Heraldry Society:

The following post produces maltese and iron crosses: How to draw an actual maltese cross?
QUESTION: How may one produce a Cross Patonce in LaTeX? Is there a specific command? If not, how may one produce something very similar to it?
Thank you.

Is it in Unicode? Do you have a font containing the symbol? If neither, have you tried to draw it? Does it have any use other than decoration?

I did not find anything like it in Unicode; I know of no font containing such a symbol; lastly, I do not know how to begin  to draw it for, unlike a maltese cross, its shape is not rigid. Any hints?

TikZ? Metapost? Inkscape? Pick your poison .... I don't know what you mean about its not being rigid.

Quick, TikZ version. You can adjust to your liking.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\foreach \t in {0,90,180,270}{
\scoped[rotate=\t]
\fill (.2,0) to[bend left=15] (.6,1.6)
    to[bend right=40] (.2,1.6)
    to[bend right] (0,1.95)
    to[bend right] (-.2,1.6)
    to[bend right=40] (-.6,1.6)
    to[bend left=15] (-.2,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Many thanks Sandy G.

Take the PostScript file you find at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cross-Patonce-Heraldry.svg
The image is declared “public domain”, so there's no usage restriction.
%!
/Patonce-arm{
300 -181 450 120 60 arcn
507.431507 239.140954 35.136986 300 60 arc
525 330.429523 60.859046 270 330 arc
525 269.570477 60.859046 30 90 arc
507.431507 360.859046 35.136986 300 60 arc
300 781 450 300 240 arcn
92.568493 360.859046 35.136986 120 240 arc
75 269.570477 60.859046 90 150 arc
75 330.429523 60.859046 210 270 arc
92.568493 239.140954 35.136986 120 240 arc
closepath fill}def
Patonce-arm
600 0 translate
90 rotate
Patonce-arm
showpage
%EOF

Save it as patonce.ps.
Now from the command line run
ps2eps patonce.ps && epstopdf patonce.eps

(not ps2pdf directly, because the bounding box would be computed wrongly). You'll get a file patonce.pdf that you can use in any LaTeX document with \includegraphics.


Thank you for posting this.
